# Add EventHandler to Content Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, master-pages

I have wired up the `Button` control on my `Master Page` in the `Content Page` as follows:

```
SiteMaster MasterPage;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
   {
      MasterPage = (SiteMaster)Page.Master;
      MasterPage.Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
   }
}

void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   MasterPage.Button1_Click(sender, e);
}
```

However, whenever I click `Button1` on the page (running under localhost), the `Page_Load` event fires!

What have I done wrong?

If it helps, the `MasterPage.Button1_Click` event runs a log in script, so there should be no recursive calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the issue here that the handler `Button1_Click` is not firing for you?

If so, the reason for this is because you are only assigning the event handler for the `Click` event on initial page load and not when the page is posting back.

Try assigning the event handler on initial load and subsequent postbacks like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MasterPage = (SiteMaster)Page.Master;
    MasterPage.Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to wire your event up in the Page_Init as opposed to the Page_Load.

as far as your button click causing Page_Load to fire. Page_Load is always going to get fired because it's part of the page lifecycle.

see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305141 for page lifecycle details.

> Page_Init: During this event, you can initialize values or connect any event handlers that you may have.

see also question: [In asp.net, page_load occuring before radio button OnCheckedChanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691833/in-asp-net-page-load-occuring-before-radio-button-oncheckedchanged-event)

Comment: OK, so where is `Page_Init` defined? Do I need to write one?

Comment: You just need to add it to your page code behind. It's defined exactly like the Page_Load.